# Is it possible to apply CSS style to the whole row inside column?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, grid-layout

Using Bootstrap 4 Grid system, I have the following structure:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MB2C7.png

I have the content column and two blank columns inside each row.
Sometimes I need to apply CSS style to the whole row.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      Lorem ipsum
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      dolor sit amet,
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
  </div>
  ....
  <div class="row custom-background-color">
    <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      consecteur adipiscing elit,
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But in the same time it becomes not handy to have multiple duplicate code. I want to regroup the code, to have column definition only once.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="row">Lorem ipsum</div>
      <div class="row">dolor sit amet,</div>
      ...
      <div class="row custom-background-color">consecteur adipiscing elit,</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I expect to have the CSS style not for one column, but for the whole page width.
Is it possible to make a workaround or find solution to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible if you have the same amount of rows in each column.
Then, you can use the [`nth-child` selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) to pass styles to e.G. the fifth row in each column.

```css
div[class^="col"] .row:nth-child(2) {
    background: green;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
     <div class="row">ipsum</div>
      <div class="row"> amet,</div>
      <div class="row"> elit,</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="row">Lorem ipsum</div>
      <div class="row">dolor sit amet,</div>
      <div class="row">consecteur adipiscing elit,</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
     <div class="row">Lorem ipsum</div>
      <div class="row">dolor</div>
      <div class="row">consecteur</div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```